# Axios throwing connection error even though postman is working for same endpoint

Tags: express, axios

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { APP_PORT } = require("./config/index");
const { CustomError, CustomErrorWithHeader, handleError } = require("./helpers/error");
const routes = require("./routes");
const app = express();
const axios = require("axios");

app.set("views", "src/views");
app.set("view-engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.disable("x-powered-by");
app.use(express.static("src/public"));


app.get("/axioshit", async(req, res) => {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4120/api/um/user/password-settings");
    res.send(response);
});

app.use(routes);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log("ERROR GENERATED", err);
    if (err instanceof CustomError) handleError(err, res);
    else if (err instanceof CustomErrorWithHeader) handleError(err, res);
    else {
        // console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Internal server error",
            statusCode: 500
        });
    }
});

app.listen(APP_PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(`Server Running On Port:${APP_PORT}`);
});
```

> (node:267) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect
> ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4120 sc-um-ui        |     at
> TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16)

I have shared the endpoint and Error.To be frank I also donot have much to go on.When I am trying to hit same endpoint with postman its working just fine.Yet Axios is throwing error.I have searched net for quite a bit yet could not find any actual answers.Most of cases people said it got resolved by itself which I am skeptical about.Can anyone help?Oh and the App is running inside a docker container

Answer (score 0):

The backend code was okay.Problem was that I wasn't exposing the docker container network externally.Hence it refused to connect to a network outside Docker container.Basically the problem was created because of docker config.